# App crashes between onPause and onResume Listview issue

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onresume, onpause

I have a listview activity which populates data through an sqlite database; however, whenever I enter onPause and then go into onResume my app crashes and I receive this error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@418106a8". Would anyone know how to stop this? Is there a method I have to call in onPause?

```
        @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfAlarms.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    listOfAlarms.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG, "Resume was called");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.i(TAG, "Pause was called");
    sqliteDatabase.close();
}



public List<String> populateList(){

        // We have to return a List which contains only String values. Lets create a List first
        List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using the DbHelper class
        AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

        // Then we need to get a readable database
         sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

        // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do it for us
        //(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
         cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_ALARM, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        // Above given query, read all the columns and fields of the table

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will not miss any by looping through a while loop
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // In one loop, cursor read one undergraduate all details
            // Assume, we also need to see all the details of each and every undergraduate
            // What we have to do is in each loop, read all the values, pass them to the POJO class
            //and create a ArrayList of undergraduates

            String alarmName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_NAME));
//            String ugUniId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_UNI_ID));
            String alarmTotalTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_ALARM_TOTALTIME));

            // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
            TestAlarm ugPojoClass = new TestAlarm();
            ugPojoClass.setTitle(alarmName);

            ugPojoClass.setTotalTime(alarmTotalTime);

            // Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains undergraduates as type
            pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

            // But we need a List of String to display in the ListView also.
            //That is why we create "uGraduateNamesList"
            uGraduateNamesList.add(alarmName);
        }

        // If you don't close the database, you will get an error
        sqliteDatabase.close();

        return uGraduateNamesList;
    }
```

Comment: Some relevant code would be helpful.

Comment: okay I added some code

Comment: Please also post `populateList()` code.

Comment: oh yeah forgot about that ok I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using deprecated methods (`startManagingCursor()`), which is dangerous.

How I see what happens: when you close your database (twice actually: in `populateList()` and `onPause()`), your cursors to this database become invalid. But since you called `startManagingCursor()`, your `Activity` retains your cursors and tries to call `requery()` on them when restarting, which throws the error.

Try not calling `startManagingCursor()` at all, just `cursor.close()` when you're done with it. Or you can migrate to newer `LoaderManager` altogether.